# Pointers : difference between * and (int *) in given context

Tags: c, pointers

```
int ar[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

statment1:  int k=(int *)((int *)(ar+1)+2);
statment2:  int l=*(*(ar+1)+2);
statement3  int *p = (int *)a +1;
```

Statement1 does not compile. 
Statement2 and Statement3 compiles.
Now, I cannot make out what difference does it make if I put `(int *)` instead of `*`, given that the array is of integer type.

Comment: `*` is to get the value of what is pointed to by a pointer, `(int *)` is a cast to integer pointer.

Comment: Maybe it's better not to compile anything…

Comment: Try to actually read, and understand, what a pointer actually _is_, then find out (by reading, trying and learning) what pointer arithmetic entails. Don't expect a 1 on 1 lesson in pointer-basics here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about dereference operator `*` and cast operation `(int *)`, and your very 1st line should have ring a bell:

```
int k = (int *)bar;
```

You try to affect an address (pointer to `int`) in an `int` variable.

The 2nd is ok because you are using `*` twice to get a value in your 2-dimension array.
The 3rd is also ok because your container `int * p` has the right type to get an address (and you dereference just "one dimension".

I hope it is clear enough, anyway you can have a look at this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) article abour dereference operator.

Answer (score 0):

the confusion appears in this line where pointers are used instead of array indexes:

```
statment1:  int k=(int *)((int *)(ar+1)+2);
```

It appears the meaning is intended to be `ar[1][2]` however, that is not what they have. In order to create an equivalent pointer representation of the `ar[1][2]` index, it would be:

```
statment1:  int k = *(*(ar + 1) + 2) // equivalent to k = ar[1][2]
```